# Unexpected behavior of ifstream (word counting)

Tags: c++, string, char, ifstream

I am trying to measure the total number words in a txt file. The file is random and consists of lines each of 10 words of length 3 to 10 and is generated by this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338964/1467434). The words in a particular line are separated by a single space. Now, the way I measure the total number of words in file is this:

```
ifstream inputFile("myfile.txt", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate );

//Count number of total words in input file
long unsigned int numWords;
inputFile.seekg(0);
char c;
while (inputFile.get(c)){
    if (isspace(c) && c != '\r') numWords++;
}

//Test
printf("\nSampled file has %lu words\n", numWords);
```

If I run the above code multiple times, half of them gets the correct result and half of them some random number. I know that there are more elegant ways to do this like

```
string word;
long unsigned int ctr = 0;
while (inputFile >> word) ctr++;
```

(or maybe others) but I would like to know why the first option fails.

Comment: Did you consider `'\n'` characters too?

Comment: Why don't you initialize `numWords` with zero?

Comment: If that's the whole program you are using, can be that `numWords` is not initialized with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with you code

1. You open file in binary mode, which makes your program platform-dependent. Line might be separated by `'\r'`, `'\n'` or `"\r\n"`. If you open in text mode, lines are guaranteed to be separated with `'\n'`.
2. Whats the point of opening file with `ios::ate` flag and immediately calling `seekg(0)`? It works, but omitting bith `ios::ate` and `seekg` has the same effect and less code to write and read.
3. You are counting space characters (excluding `'\r'`), not words. Including double spaces, `'\n'` characters at the end of line and similar.
4. And the most probable root cause - uninitialized variable `numWords`. Using it invokes undefined behavior. In your case random results is the most probable effect.